# Copy/Paste of Range

Tags: excel, vba, performance

I have gone through all steps to optimize the code, deactivating screenupdate, deactivating calculation, events, and pagebreaks removed the unnecessary selects, adding constants, and etc. However, I don't think my algorithm for coping is the best one, even if it is probably the simplest of them all.

```
For Each cell In currentRange
    If cell = vbNullString Then Exit For    
    cell.Select
    cellValue = cell.Value
    If cellValue = "x" Then                    
            Sheets(sourceData).Activate              
            'ActiveCell.Offset(0, -Selection.Column + 1).Range("F1:L1").Select          
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, -Selection.Column + 1).Range("F1:L1").Copy         
            Sheets(pasteSheet).Activate         
            Rows(destinationCell).Select            
            Set destinationRange = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -Selection.Column + 1).Range("F1:L1")           
            'destinationRange.Select            
            destinationRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues         
            Rows(destinationCell).Range("H1").Cut           
            Rows(destinationCell).Range("G1").Insert            
            'ActiveCell.Offset(0, -Selection.Column + 1).Range("F1:L1").Select          
            destinationCell = destinationCell + 1           
            Worksheets(sourceData).Select           
    End If
Next
```

I copy a range from a row into another sheet, while shifting values from H to G column. I did not manage to create this functionality with .Copy Destination:=, which I think is faster.

What would be the best way to optimizing this code?

Comment: See VBA best practices, particularly the part about [avoiding the use of select/activate.](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/9292/avoid-using-select-or-activate#t=201612080854300790375)

Comment: explain in better detail what's your goal: what do you want to copy from and paste to? Are you interested in values only?

Comment: See my answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29596432/pointers-needed-for-speeding-up-nested-loop-macro-in-vba/29597193#29597193. Note programs should not use the clipboard. The clipboard is the user's tool not the programmers.

Comment: Use range(dest).value=range(source).value when you can

Answer (score 1):

Copying/pasting is never a good idea.  Look at noodles link.  You should use something like this....

```
Sheets("receivinigSheet").Range("A2:F2") = Sheets("sendingSheet").Range("A2:F2").Value
```